# Datagridview multiselect is not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

We have a datagridview. Its multiselect property is set to true.
This datagridview will update its rows in a particular interval time say one or two seconds.

So suppose i will select a row and then hold shift key and select another row, then the whole rows between these two is selected without any issue.

Suppose if i select a row and after that the gridview is updated, and then if i am trying to select another row by holding the shift key , then its not selecting the whole rows, instead the last clicked row is selected.

So i am not sure why its happening, so its like if i am selecting the 2nd row of the grid and updation may be this row is moved down say 5th row, and after that i am trying to select another row holding shift key, then this error is happening.

Anyone please give your suggestions on this issue.

### code for selection after updation

```
for (int nRow = 0; nRow < Grid.Rows.Count; nRow++)
{
  foreach (string cookieIdval in SelectedCookies)
  {
     if (Grid.Rows[nRow].Cells[ColCookieID].Value.ToString() == cookieIdval.ToString())
     {
       Grid.Rows[nRow].Cells[ColCookieID].Selected = true;
       break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: How you update datagridview?

Comment: I'm confused with your question. Are you expecting it not to select all the rows in between when you Shift select? And if I understood you wrong, and if you want to select many rows while they are updating, it doesn't sound like a good thing to me.

Comment: @hattenn : sorry for the confusion. What i want is the multiselect should work in all cases whether or not the gridview updated. ie it should select multiple rows in all cases.. hope you clear this..

Comment: But what is your expected behavior? If you choose the rows between the first and the tenth, and if the second row moves to 50th place? Do you still want it selected? So when you select rows, which state will be used to pick the data rows? Before updation, or after?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : its using a subsrciption technique. so whenever there is a change in some properties or the columns in the gridview it will update the gridview.

Comment: @hattenn: its not like that suppose if i am selecting between 1st and 10th row and after updation if first row is moved to 50th place then 10th row will be in the 60th place only.. in that way we are doing the updation. And we have managed to done that also ie after updation the rows from 50th to 60th will be selected. The issue after this if i try to select the 65th row by holding shift key then this should select rows from 50 to 65, but instead it is only selecting 65th row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your update method such that it resotres what have been selected before update. Use [`DataGridViewRow.Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx) and [`DataGridView.CurrentRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx) properties.

The way you do this depends on how your DataGridView is being populated.

**EDIT:**

It seems that the key to distinguish your rows are in `ColCookieID` column. We could use that to store and recover selected rows:

```
public void UpdateGridView()
{
    HashSet<string> selectedRows = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Selected)
            selectedRows.Add(row.Cells[ColCookieID].Value.ToString());
    }
    var currentRow = grid.CurrentRow.Cells[ColCookieID].Value.ToString()

    // ... update the grid

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        var id = row.Cells[ColCookieID].Value.ToString();
        if (selectedRows.Contains(id))
            row.Selected = true;
        if (currentRow == id)
            grid.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: The current row is the first row in the selected rows list. right?

Comment: @mahesh No. I guess it is the last row you clicked on it.

Comment: @mahesh It whould be helpful if we could have some code from the updater method.

Comment: @mahesh :-) I just needed the code that actually **updates** the DataGridView, not the code you've written after my answer. BTW, you are doing right. The only remaining thing is `CurrentRow`. You should store that before updating, and restore it after updating.

Comment: ah the original code is almost like that only.. i jst modified the variable names and some comments..

Comment: setting the current cell property worked for me since we can't set the current row. Also i took one cell in the top most row of selected rows.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you postpone update until user interraction like this ends?

Comment: as i said the updation is happening continously in a second and we can't postpone this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to address the actual problem (shift key does not work for multiselect after refresh) - this is fixed by setting

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell = ...
```

(setting CurrentCell is contained in the accepted answer, but this specific issue has not been mentioned)